NextJS 14 with Next-intl making every page dynamic which cause a huge performance problem
i have next-intl setup like this and its making every page dynamic which has impact in performance

import { NextIntlClientProvider } from "next-intl";
import { getMessages } from "next-intl/server";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import LocaleSwitcher from "@/components/LocalSwitcher";
import { poppinsFont } from "@/lib/utils/font";

export default async function LocaleLayout({
  children,
  params: { locale },
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { locale: string };
}) {
  const messages = await getMessages();
  return (
    <html lang={locale} className={cn("min-h-screen", poppinsFont.variable)}>
      <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/ipi_logo_portrait.png" sizes="any" as="style" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <main>
          <NextIntlClientProvider messages={messages}>
            <div className="relative">
              {children}
              <div className="absolute -top-4 md:top-0 right-0">
                <LocaleSwitcher />
              </div>
            </div>
          </NextIntlClientProvider>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

is there any work around to fix this
this is my pages inside my app directory

this is build output of pages

i have tried using
export const dynamic = "force-static"
i don't like this like using in every page also like if i do this in the layout page and do export const dynamic = "force-dynamic" in dynamic pages when i build it making the whole page dynamic still i really a appriciate if anyone got a work around for this issue

Read the docs https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router/with-i18n-routing#static-rendering
